# Need to efficiently scans for low end ascii control characters on large excel files

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I am working on an ETL Validation procedure to scan for invalid ascii chars prior to processing. In this case, invalid is defined as ascii chars in the 0-31 range.

In a C# ETL validation service I am using OfficeOpenXml to examine the contents of the excel files.

Does anyone know of a more efficient way to search the contents besides looping each worksheet, each column and each row? The files can be very large and the validation should be as fast a possible.

Is there access to the raw xml buffer? Would it be faster to un-zip the xml files and scan the content there?

Comment: The fastest way I've done similar is using variant arrays in a subroutine and looping, using a function to iterate through the different invalid characters, so that everything happens in memory, rather than acting upon the sheet itself.  It still took a few minutes to perform on ~30 sheets, each over 500k lines (note that only 2 columns per sheet had to be checked).  My "output" was flagging the lines with invalid characters, so I did have to write to sheet when the function matched the condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think it is time for the Speed Rant: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

The question is, where the bottleneck is right now. My instict tells me it **should** be the disk. You are working with files, so it usually is the Disk. If that is the case, short of loading each cell into memory only once, there is not much to speed up.

You are however doing a pretty deep processing of strings, as you will have to go through every char. So there might be a *relevant* amount of time spend on that. Most likely not the bottleneck, but something you can negate as cost.

You might be able to do some asynchronisation, having the next cell/row loading in background while you process this one. A approach like `Directory.EnumerateFiles()` vs `Directory.GetFiles` might work: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles

Row does seem to have a [GetEnumerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.openxmlelement.getenumerator) function. But it might just be there to get a Enumerator for code that *requires* Enuemrators and not actually include defered/background loading (i.e. like the Enumerator implicitly created for foreach loops).

Comment: You persuaded me to write some tests around the scanning for invalid chars. I am going first try an elongated three dimensional array[] with column, row and value references and then run that through 5 different string routines I have found to be the best for this type of deal. Just for curiosity, I will do the same with a List<Cell> and run that through a Parallel.ForEach(string parser function). Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote test harness and came up with 14 variations using string[] and List for data structures and the following iterators:

1 :
    `foreach (char c in s.ToCharArray())`

2 :

```
byte[] ASCIIValues = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
foreach (byte code in ASCIIValues)
```

3 :

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"/[^ -~]/", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(s);
```

4 :

```
for(int x=0; x < s.Length; x++)
```

- Under 100,000 items with a foreach iteration over a string[] using method 2 had the fastest average time.
- Over 100,000 items using Parallel.ForEach on a string[] using method 2 averaged the fastest.
- Over 1,000,000 items using Parallel.ForEach on a string[] using method 1 averaged the fastest.
- Under 10,000 items using Parallel.ForEach on a string[] or List<> using all methods was the slowest.
- With no parallelism, 1 overtook 2 as the fastest as the number of items passed 500,000(??)
- The Regex was always slower compared to iterating chars or bytes
- For anything around 100,000 a foreach loop using string[] and method 2 was the fastest